# Http client mode with Contiki?

Tags: contiki

I want to make a webAPI call from a sensor using http, is it possible to do http requests using Contiki OS?

As far as I've searched I found only coap client examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `examples/http-socket` example, it shows how to use CRUD methods such as PUT, GET, etc.

Here's the link [to the example](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/examples/http-socket/http-example.c) (working with the latest [master commit](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/commit/40f81a98c333f7118a1bc4758ed0aa212576cc70))

This example relies on IP64, but can be changed to work with IPv6, basically you need to include the `http-socket` library.  Here are the more relevant parts of the example:

```
#include "contiki-net.h"
#include "http-socket.h"
#include "ip64-addr.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static struct http_socket s;
static int bytes_received = 0;

static void
callback(struct http_socket *s, void *ptr,
         http_socket_event_t e,
         const uint8_t *data, uint16_t datalen)
{
  if(e == HTTP_SOCKET_ERR) {
    printf("HTTP socket error\n");
  } else if(e == HTTP_SOCKET_DATA) {
    bytes_received += datalen;
    printf("HTTP socket received %d bytes of data\n", datalen);
  }
}

PROCESS_THREAD(http_example_process, ev, data)
{
  PROCESS_BEGIN();

  /* Initializes the socket */
  http_socket_init(&s);

  /* GET request */
  http_socket_get(&s, "http://www.contiki-os.org/", 0, 0,
                  callback, NULL);

  /* Waits forever for the HTTP callback */
  while(1) {
    PROCESS_WAIT_EVENT_UNTIL(0);
  }

  PROCESS_END();
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include the link to the example. But it is best practice to put the essential parts of your solution directly in your Stack Overflow answer anyway in case the example link expires in the future so please put the example directly in your answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my answer including the link to the example and a reference to a working commit, so in case the link expires, one could do a `git checkout SHA1` and retrieve the example... is this OK?

Comment: What happens if the repository disappears? You should put the code for the essential parts of the solution directly in your answer, that way your answer will still be useful if the repository/example at the external link disappears.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes you can do that:**

What I understand is that you are looking for `Websense Example` in `Contiki OS`.it uses `HTTP` protocl.

**A: so find this file.**

```
~/contiki/examples/zolertia/z1/ipv6/z1-websense/z1-websense.c
```

1. Burn it on Sender Mote.
2. Burn `border-router.c` file located in `/home/superuser/contiki/examples/ipv6/rpl-border-router/`
3. Connect Border Router with `tunnelslip` with command `make connect-router`.
4. use the `HTTP` `IPV6` url shown by `tunnelslip` on connection.
5. this url in browser will give you address of motes connected to it.
6. use that sender mote address in web browser and see the mote output.

**B: or from contiki/cooja simulator:**

launch this project file. this is working demo for the websense.

```
~contiki/examples/zolertia/z1/ipv6/z1-websense/example-z1-websense.csc
```

and repeat from step 3.

for further you can ask me.